# How to catch concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError correctly when using asyncio.wait_for and asyncio.Semaphore?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, semaphore

First of all, i need to warn you: I'm new to asyncio, and i h
I warn you right away, I'm new to asyncio, and I can hardly imagine what is in the library under the hood.

Here is my code:

```
import asyncio

semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(50)

async def work(value):
    async with semaphore:
        print(value)
        await asyncio.sleep(10)

async def main():
    tasks = []
    for i in range(0, 10000):
        tasks.append(asyncio.wait_for(work(i), timeout=3))
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
future = asyncio.ensure_future(main())
loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

What i need: Coroutine work() to be completed for no more than 3 seconds, and no more than 50 pieces at a same time. After 3 seconds (timeout), the coroutine work() must stop execution, and a new 50 tasks must start to work. But in my case, after 3 seconds crashes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/root/PycharmProjects/LogParser/ssh/async/asyn_test.py", line 19, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(future)
  File "C:\Code\Python3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 579, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:/Users/root/PycharmProjects/LogParser/ssh/async/asyn_test.py", line 15, in main
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Code\Python3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 449, in wait_for
    raise futures.TimeoutError()
concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError
```

Whatever I had not tried to catch this exception, no matter how many tasks remained, program breaks down. I need, upon reaching timeout, the program continued to the next tasks
 Please, teach me, how do I need properly implement this?

Python 3.7, asyncio 3.4.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to handle the exception. If you just pass it to `gather`, it will re-raise it. For example, you can create a new coroutine with the appropriate try/except:

```
semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(50)

async def work(value):
    print(value)
    await asyncio.sleep(10)

async def work_with_timeout(value):
    async with semaphore:
        try:
            return await asyncio.wait_for(work(value), timeout=3)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            return None

async def main():
    tasks = []
    for i in range(0, 10000):
        tasks.append(work_with_timeout(i))
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

Comment: I tried your code. Only the first 50 tasks are completed. When the time-out comes, the remaining 9950 tasks break.

Comment: I will explain in more detail.
In your code, the timeout works for all tasks.
For example, if you put asyncio.sleep (1) in work (), and timeout = 3, then the output will print (1 - 149) and then the rest will fall into TimeoutError and will never be executed.
I need a separate timeout for each task.

When each coroutine will have 3 seconds to do the job.
If a coroutine receives a timeout, then the current coroutine stop work, but whole tasks work does not stop, but all tasks are performed.
But at the same time no more than the amount specified in semaphore.

Comment: @RomanIsakov The timeout works per-task, but it counts the time spent waiting for the semaphore. I've now edited the answer to exclude the semaphore-waiting time from the timeout.